# Webdriver :Element is not clickable at point (119, 9). Other element would receive the click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Scenario:

Login to www.flipkart.com and choose "Samsung" from "Electronics" after successful login.
Now, I need to scroll to the bottom of the page and from the left side, I need click on Availability to choose the "Exclude out of stock option" but 
on clicking Availability, I am getting the message

> FAILED: Test_Samsung
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (119, 9). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="_1H5F__" data-reactid="10"></div>`
>   Command duration or timeout: 133 milliseconds

```
//class for successful flipkart login
public class Flipkart_Login 
{

@FindBy(xpath="//a[text()='Log In']") WebElement Login_Click;
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='_2zrpKA' and @type='text']") WebElement Enter_Email;
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv' and @type='password']") WebElement Enter_Pass;
@FindBy(xpath="//button[@type='submit' and @class='_3zLR9i _1LctnI _36SmAs']") WebElement Login_Button;
@FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Please enter valid Email ID/Mobile number']") WebElement Blank_Email;
@FindBy(xpath="//span[text()='Please enter Password']") WebElement Blank_Pass;

public void Valid_Login()
{
    Login_Click.click();
    Enter_Email.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
    Enter_Pass.sendKeys("abcde");
    Login_Button.click();

}

}
//class for choosing Samsung from Electronics menu and clicking Availability
public class Flipkart_Electronics_Samsung_Mobile 
{

@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Electronics']//span[text()='Electronics']") WebElement Electronics_Menu;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Samsung']//span[text()='Samsung']") WebElement Samsung_Mobile_Click;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='_3QT2gR _1AgMas']//div[text()='Availability']") WebElement Availability;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='_1p7h2j']") WebElement Exclude_Out_Of_Stock;


public void Choose_Samsung_Mobile()
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(Electronics_Menu).perform();
    act.click(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Samsung']//span[text()='Samsung']")))).build().perform();

    WebElement Availability = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='_3QT2gR _1AgMas']//div[text()='Availability']")));

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Availability);
    Availability.click();

}
}

//class which calls the methods from above two classes

public class Flipkart_Electronics_Samsung_Search 
{

WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void Test_Samsung()
{
    driver = BrowserFactory.getBrowser("Firefox");
    driver.get(DataProviderFactory.getConfig().getURL());

    Flipkart_Login login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Flipkart_Login.class);
    login.Valid_Login();

    Flipkart_Electronics_Samsung_Mobile Samsung = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Flipkart_Electronics_Samsung_Mobile.class);
    Samsung.Choose_Samsung_Mobile();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to click using `JavascriptExecutor` So you should replace below line :-

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Availability);
Availability.click();
```

To

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Availability);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Element is not clickable at point (119, 9). Other element would receive the click:  Command duration or timeout: 133 milliseconds

It clearly says, the element we want to click is hidden by some other element div in this case, which would receive the click.

I think it is problem with UI which shouldn't hide the element, but you can try few things : 
1. Maximize the window of browser from webdriver to see if element is still hidden

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

Use JavaScript to click element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.<locator>);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element)
```